# WPF MVVM using TPL - should I handle exceptions in the back or front end?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM application, the WPF is the UI frontend and I have another project in the same solution that does DB access, I do this by starting a Task from the frontend that executes the backend DB access method.

I'm wondering what is the best practice to handle exceptions in this case? I'm thinking the backend should handle exceptions that it can do something about and maybe fix, while unfixable problems like "Can't connect to the database" should be shown to the user by checking if the Task object's "Exception" property is not null?

Comment: The "best practice" is the one that most effectively meets your specific requirements.  What are your specific requirements?

Comment: (in other words, you need to think about the problem, what "effective" specifically means to you and your project, and do the thing that is most "effective.")

Comment: All that said, in my WPF MVVM (which uses the Prism framework) application, there is an event that fires in the Application class when any *unhandled* exception occurs.  For things like database access failures, all it can really do is display an error message and terminate the current action.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought there'd be a best practice on whether the front or the back should handle exceptions? Like how it is said in MVVM the view shouldn't have any program logic and the ViewModel shouldn't have any display logic.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are no such things as "best practices,"  at least not in the way you're describing them.  There are only better practices based on past experiences with specific goals, and reasons why those practices are better.  Since the only way to determine if one strategy is better than another is to evaluate it in the context of your specific situation, you still have to think about your problem and devise a reasonable strategy for solving it.

Comment: Ergo, to even begin to formulate an answer to the question you posed, I would have to ask a flock of questions about your project first.  Questions like: "what do you want to accomplish with your exception handling?  What does that look like from within your own code?"  I think if you ask yourself those questions and answer them in detail, the "best practice" should become obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of handling an exception is to either recover, (that is, put the system back into a safe secure well defined state) or log, rethrow, and halt the system.

The “best practice” in either case is to do that where you can do that. In some places you won’t  know enough context to do that. You should avoid such places.

You were probably hoping for some one size fits all answer that you could follow without thinking. Sorry but that simply doesn’t exist. Trying to make one exist would put unreasonable restrictions on your coding style.

What you can do is plan well so you can keep your recovery plans simple. That requires a system that isn’t difficult to put into a defined state. Or a lot of  crashing.

Sorry, no silver bullet here.